# What does [Symbols.serialize]() do here?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am seeing this code:

```
// main.js
const Symbols = require('../symbols');

[Symbols.serialize]() {
  ...
  return super[Symbols.serialize]();
}


// symbols.js
module.exports = {
   serialize: Symbol('serialize')
};
```

I am slowly getting ES6 but this one thing escapes me. What does it actually do?

Comment: `Symbols`? [That's not standard...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) Where is that from?

Comment: Ah, correct. I added a bit of code that "defines" Symbol... and it's still very unclear

Comment: Looking at the [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) documentation, `'serialize'` is just a name, it has no function.

Comment: `Symbols` or `Symbol`? JS isn't even case-insensitive, let alone pluralization-insensitive...

Comment: `Symbols` still looks undefined, what you require is `Symbol`. A typo? Anyway, `Symbol.serialize` looks like just someone's custom symbol. Aren't you familar with these? https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/

Comment: Fixed question and code's typo (extra 's', missing semicolon)

Comment: Your `[Symbol.serialize]() { .. }` code is actually inside of a `class` that you aren't showing, correct? (I assume since this isn't valid as top-level syntax, and the use of `super` implies a `class`.)

Comment: @Merc Your question (text and its title) still refer to `Symbols`

Comment: It's late night. Sorry.

Comment: Short answer: you can replace all `[Symbol.serialize]` by `mySerialize`, then you can understand the code more easily. For detailed explanation, you can refer to my answer. If you have any question, just tell us :)

Comment: I totally get it now. I am sorry, it's really late and time for bed on this part of the planet... I fixed the question for the sake of people coming to read it (and for the sake of people who answered)

Comment: If it helps, you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read this first:  http://2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html (especially `1.1 Symbols as property keys`)

In your example: You created a symbol called `Symbols.serialize` in `symbol.js`, then you use this symbol as function name to define a function.

Just imagine that `[Symbols.serialize]` is like `mySerialize`, then

```
[Symbols.serialize]() {
  ...
  return super[Symbols.serialize]();
}
```

is like

```
function mySerialize() {
  ...
  return super['mySerialize']();
}
```

(not exactly, just for example ONLY)

MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Then let's guess about the design pattern in your example. To make things easy, I will use `mySerialize` as the function name instead of `[Symbols.serialize]`, you can just think that they are the same and do same things.

The author is implementing a serialization framework (Serialization means saving all properties of a object to a string or byte-stream. De-serialization means recovering a object from the string or byte-stream).

Every class implements its own `mySerialize` function. In this function, the properties of this class are serialized, and of course, they are serialized with super class's properties by calling `super['mySerialize']()`.

```
class TheDemoBase {
    mySerialize() {
        return my_serialization_result
    }
}

class TheDemoClass extends TheDemoBase {

    mySerialize() {

        // serialize all properties of `this`
        do_serialize(this.a)
        do_serialize(this.b)

        // call TheDemoBase.mySerialize()
        combine_serialization(super['mySerialize']())  

        return result
    }
}
```

Then, replace all `mySerialize` to `[Symbols.serialize]`, that's what you see.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `[someVar]() { }` is syntax for defining a function property with a variable-defined name. For example:

```
var someVar = "foo";

class Foo {
    [someVar]() { }
}

var myObj = {
    [someVar]() { }
}
```

This will create a class and an object with a property called `foo`, since that's what `someVar` happened to hold at the time.

In the case of `[Symbol.serialize]() { ... }`, the property name happens to be a `Symbol` value instead of a string (since ES6, property names may be strings or may be unique `Symbol` values). The value of `Symbol.serialize` happens to be the `Symbol` object produced by `Symbol('serialize')`, just as the value of `someVar` was the string `"foo"` in my first example.

The output of `Symbol('serialize')` is just a unique symbol with an internal `[[Description]]` slot set to the string `serialize`.